# What happens if I don't close a txt file

Tags: python, file-io, raspberry-pi

I'm about to write a program for a racecar, that creates a txt and continuously adds new lines to it. Unfortunately I can't close the file, because when the car shuts off the raspberry (which the program is running on) gets also shut down. So I have no chance of closing the txt.

Is this a problem?

Comment: @FunctionR could always turn off buffering or forcibly flush the file though...

Comment: Why did this question get three downvotes?  "Is failing to close a text file I'm writing to going to be a problem?" is a reasonable enough question, with a perfectly sensible answer.

Comment: One obvious question is, how is the raspberry pi shutdown? If they pull the power, there is nothing you can do, but if the system is shut down normally, there are a few options.

Comment: The power will be pulled. Unfortunately there is no way of letting it shut down.

Comment: If they're going to simply pull the power, you may have bigger problems than just missing data. Every time you start up, the raspberry is going to have to check the filing system for consistency, and it is inevitable that at some point either the FS or some file is going to be corrupted.

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no. Data is buffered at different places in the process of writing: the file object of python, the underlying C-functions, the operating system, the disk controller. Even closing the file, does not guarantee, that all these buffers are written physically. Only the first two levels are forced to write their buffers to the next level. The same can be done by flushing the filehandle without closing it.
As long as the power-off can occur anytime, you have to deal with the fact, that some data is lost or partially written.
Closing a file is important to give free limited resources of the operating system, but this is no concern in your setup.

Comment: Thank you, then I guess I'll just do it without closing